# Textarea with height: auto and line breaks

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a textarea with some text on it, and the text has some line breaks on it, if I set my style to:

```
textarea {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
}
```

When I load the page, then the text area will only automatically set the height of the textarea until it finds the first line break, example:

For a textarea with this text:

```
This is an

example text
```

When the page is loaded, the textarea will be shown as:

```
This is an
```

Browser thinks line breaks are the end of the whole text. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The text is still there if you use the arrow keys to move down, it's just that the textarea by default isn't tall enough to show all the text. You can use the `rows` attribute to define now many rows of text the textarea should have by default.

Alternatively, if you want more control you can use a `div` with the attribute `contenteditable="true"`.

```css
textarea {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
}

/*
* CSS for div with contenteditable="true"
*/
.textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="3">This is an

example text
</textarea>

<div class="textarea" contenteditable="true">This is an

example text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, contenteditable is a nice workaround, I can't use it because my textarea is used by my app (rails) on a form to be sent in an ajax request, but otherwise I would do this.

Answer (score 0):

To any one reading this, the solution I came up with is simple. With JQuery, on document ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var trueHeight = $( '#your_textarea' ).prop( 'scrollHeight' );
  $( '#your_textarea' ).height( trueHeight );
});
```

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.textarea {
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea"><p>This is an</p><p>example text</p></div>
```

Please check the above code.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `rows` attribute to set the height of your textarea.

```
<textarea rows='100'>this is an
example text</textarea>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvw7s1rz/2/

Comment: Needs to be automatic, if I only have 1 line I wouldn't want 99 empty lines there

Comment: It doesn't need to be 100 rows. You can set it to any number of rows you want. If you only have one line of text then this won't be a problem anyway. For example, if you have 6 rows (and five are being hidden) then you can just use `<textarea rows='6'>`